# MVC retrieving a binary image from database downloads the image but i need to show it

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

hello guys i'm retrieving an image from database , it's stored as a binary field
here is the code i use

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int? id)
{
    byte[] img=.......//get image from db
    string imgType = "image/jpeg";
    return File(img, imgType);
}
```

but the problem is that code downloads the image , and i need to show the image not to download it,

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: how are you rendering it in your markup?

Comment: I tried your code in Chrome and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the content type wrongly - make sure it's `image/jpeg`, `image/png` and so on.